# Backbone model not instantiated

Tags: backbone.js

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min1.4.js"></script>
<script>
//MODEL CREATION
var person=Backbone.Model.extend(
        { 
            initialize: function()
            {
                alert("hello backbone");
            }

        });     


        function perf()
{


            var val=new person();   

    }

        </script>   
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="perf()">CLICK</button>


</body>
</html>
```

This is a simple code, alert is not invoked in the model when an instance of it is created in the perf() function which is called while clicking the button... Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's jsfiddle that included both suggestions by dcarson & Naresh J ,  http://jsfiddle.net/Rvn2L/1/

```
$(function () {
    var person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            alert("hello backbone");
        }
    });
    function perf() {
        console.log('1');
        var val = new person();
    }
    window.perf = perf;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to write your code in `$(function() {});` block or `$(document).ready(function () {});` block.

It should work.

Comment: Then perf must be made available to the window   window.perf = perf;

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a script reference to Underscore.js

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
```

Backbone requires it as a dependency.

Download it at http://underscorejs.org/ then put it above your script element for backbone.js and it will work fine.

Comment: Have you checked whether your reference to "jquery-min1.4.js" is correctly written? It looks weird to me so you may want to check that the src reference is correct. I'd expect the format to be "jquery-1.4.min.js" Anyway, you can see the fiddle posted by slobodan.blazeski working and the only thing your code is missing compared to his fiddle is the reference to underscore.js, which is the correct answer. You might try to look in your browser's console? It will tell you the javascript error that is occuring.